# How to trigger a Jenkins build in Gerrit Trigger on change to project subdirectory

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I want to trigger a Jenkins build with Gerrit Trigger only when a change to a file in a specific sub-directory is made. For example...

```
├── subdir1
│   ├── trigger
│   ├── also-trigger
├── subdir2
│   ├── do-not-trigger
```

If any change to a file in subdir1 is made I want to trigger a build.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Add File Path` or the `Add Forbidden File Path`?

Answer (score 3):

Check `Gerrit event` in your Jenkins project configuration. In Gerrit settings `Add File path` with `path` `subdir1` (of course you should set project and branches patterns). Then any changes in `subdir1` will activate Jenkins, and changes from `subdir2` will be ignore by Jenkins.

Comment: Not able to build project when only want to build subproject folder, it should come under project or file path?  project e.g. value project_name_on_gerrit/subproject or in the filepath

Comment: Most probably you forgot to set `Path` type in dropdown list instead of `Plain`. In my case I have set `Pattern (Plain): Repo name`, `Pattern (Path): **` (means any branch), `File path (Path): subdir1/**` (means any modified file inside `subdir1`).

Answer (score 2):

There's an unexpected behaviour with Gerrit Trigger plugin when you select "Ref Updated" as the trigger event. It does not care about File Path option. But if you have a UI pull request way of doing things, it means you'll be merging changes through UI. So, you can try using "Change Merged" on "Trigger on" section.

Having a look at the parameters of the job, when a change-merged is triggered, there is information about the changeset that triggers the build. On the contrary, when you use ref-updated, there's no information about the changeset, so it is not possible to check for file inclusion. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=2483